# Recreate activity or just take it from task?

Tags: android, android-activity, task, back-button

the question is a bit malformed. Sorry.
I wanted to say that when you click software back button (**actionBar 'up' button** - created by android, when you established parentActivity in manifest) that button recreates an activity that is considered "father" (if i'm not wrong).

But i can override that with something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In that way if i understand correctly activity is not recreated. Activity on top just finish()ed and we see activity that was under it saved in task. Right?

**Considering that i am not passing any data back**, what should i use or what is better: default or overrided behavior? What risks i run into if i will not recreate an activity and override the method changing the behavior? can an activity from task be lost? ( in case i am saying wth things right now, pls excuse me :D )

Comment: Calling onBackPressed() has the same effect as clicking the back button.

Comment: both things are same.

Comment: First understand the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). When you press back button `onBackPressed()` is called. Which will call `onRestart()` of previous activity.

Comment: i had an activity that was used in more places and without overriding on Android ver. 4.3 and under i have had problems with that button. because in 9/10 cases it wasn't called from his father.

Comment: ActionBar 'up' button. I am speaking about that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use this

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true; 
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

rather than this,

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Reason:**

When you apply the second approach, `FirstActivity` will be launched again that means `onCreate()` will be called, whether in first approch `onRestart()` will be called as I suggested in comment.

> **Note:** If you want to reload `FirstActivty` on `android.R.id.home`press
>   event, use second approch.